# switch between two cases using GOTO

Tags: c#, uwp, switch-statement, goto

I want to switch between 2 cases using goto (when case 1 is run, goto case 2, then when case 2 is run, goto case 1 again, and so on) but after case 2, case 1 doesn't work.
Here is my code:

```
case 1:
    //Create a new picker
    FileOpenPicker filePicker = new FileOpenPicker();

    //Add filetype filters.  In this case wmv and mp4.
    filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".wmv");
    filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp4");

    filePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.VideosLibrary;

    StorageFile file = await filePicker.PickSingleFileAsync();

    if (file != null)
    {
        mediaPlayerElement.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromStorageFile(file);
        mediaPlayerElement.MediaPlayer.Play();
    }

    openButton.Content = "Close";
    break;
case 2:
    mediaPlayerElement.Source = null;
    openButton.Content = "Open";
    goto case 1;
```

Comment: move your logic into functions
call the functions and DO NOT use gotos your code will be impossible to understand otherwise

Comment: Define "doesn't work". It throws an exception (which one)? It doesn't behave as expected (what did you expected and what did you get)? Also, why don't use a `while` instead of `goto`?

Comment: case 1 ends with `break;`, so it won't goto case 2

Comment: @RobinBennett When I did goto case 2 it opened the file browser, and every time I closed the file browser, it opened again, so I had to press alt-f4 3 times to get the program closed.

Comment: Isn't that what you want? It's what your question is asking for.

Comment: Well, your program is doing what you told it to do. It asks for a file, you select the file and close the dialog, then the program is running your entire code and returns to case 1, where it asks for a file again.

Comment: one reason why people try to avoid gotos....

Answer (score 0):

You should always avoid using `gotos` or your code will become unreadable.
Use functions for that purpose!

```
        switch (i)
        {
            case 1:
                closeToOpen();
                openToClose();

                break;
            case 2:
                openToClose();
                closeToOpen();
        default:
                break;
        }
    }

    void openToClose()
    {
        mediaPlayerElement.Source = null;
        openButton.Content = "Open";
    }

    void closeToOpen()
    {
        FileOpenPicker filePicker = new FileOpenPicker();

        //Add filetype filters.  In this case wmv and mp4.
        filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".wmv");
        filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp4");

        filePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.VideosLibrary;

        StorageFile file = await filePicker.PickSingleFileAsync();

        if (file != null)
        {
            mediaPlayerElement.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromStorageFile(file);
            mediaPlayerElement.MediaPlayer.Play();
        }

        openButton.Content = "Close";
    }
```

Not sure if this is exactly what you were trying to achive but if not use it as a guide!